# Injecting a service inside a service uncaught error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I'm trying to inject a service inside another service:

- instagram.service > event.service.ts(main service)
  Where the instagram is the service that is going to be injected inside the event.service.

I have declared the instagram.service.ts in the app.module.

The error that I get is:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Instagram: (?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata
>   (compiler.js:10922)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata
>   (compiler.js:10815)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata
>   (compiler.js:11037)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata
>   (compiler.js:11046)
>       at compiler.js:10984
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata
>   (compiler.js:10944)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   (compiler.js:10663)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.js:23876)

After running some tests I noticed that the error only happens when I import the **Http** component (that's also declared on the app.module).

Am I missing something here?

**events.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Event } from './events.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Instagram } from './instagram.service';

@Injectable()

export class EventService {
    event: AngularFireList<Event[]>;
    NODE = 'events/';

    constructor(private instagram: Instagram, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

    getAllPictures(tag: string) {
        this.instagram.getAllPictures(tag);
    }
}
```

**instagram.service.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
export class Instagram {
    tag: string;
    private BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + this.tag + '/?__a=1';
    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    getAllPictures(tag: string) {
        this.tag = tag;
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL).pipe().subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: try use HttpClient instead of http

Comment: Hey @bat7 I tried that but still got the same error. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@Injectable()`

to your `Instagram`  service

Good lock!

Comment: It worked! WOOOOW! Thank you much! I thought that the `@Injectable()` was only to be added on the class that would get another thing injected to. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported `HttpModule` in your `AppModule`?

Keep in mind that with Angular 5 you could use `HttpClient` because `Http` is deprecated now. For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/http.

Comment: Hey @Георги Стоименов I followed this suggestion but I still get the same error. Is there anything else I could try? Thank you

Comment: Hmm..  we will need more information. Try to reproduce it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-entmfb and share it with us. Also @bat7 has a point about the missing `@Injectable()` in your `Instagram` service.

Comment: That was it. Thank you sooo much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to Inject anything, it has to have the @Injectable() annotation.
That annotation basically flags the class for angular to track and provide to requesting classes.

Just to clarify a bit (looking at your comment it seems that it is not clear how Angular DI works):
Classes that will be injected needs an @Injectable annotation
Classes with requires an injected element do so by specifying an @Inject(InjectableClassName) argument in the constructor.
These things apply to all classes.

There's a caveat though, which is probably what is confusing you:
Classes already "registered" by angular by any means (meaning they have either @Injectable, @Component, @Pipe or @Directive annotation) have a shortcut for their constructor: they dont need the @Inject(..) argument, but that argument will be automatically resolved by indicating the type and an access keyword (just like you did, since EventService has @Injectable). This is only an "implicit" inject, angular will process it the same way.

I think it is important to say this because the type is only one of the possible "DI tokens".
For instance I have in one of my project this constructor:

```
    constructor(private eventService: EventService, @Inject(SERVICE_IMPLEMENTATIONS_MAP) private serviceMap: any) {}
```

As you can see, the type of serviceMap is any, but I do inject it via a Dependency Token I provide in the containing module, and I can actually pass anything to it (which I use for different type of mocks and actual service which have no common API). As you can see, I also use the shortcut DI for the other service though.

Bear in mind, @Injectable *doent mean* its constructor can be injected. It means the class can be injected elsewhere.
With your code, I can write somewhere constructor(private e: EventService) and Angular will inject me your eventservice (with the instagram service injected again). Injectables dont get other things injected to them, they do get injected in other things.